# Setting a Column in SQL to the Resultant Column when Summing Two Different Columns

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have seen tutorials on how to add columns together when they are from the same table; however, I have not seen how to return the resultant column of an addition of two columns and then set that result to a brand new column.

The code below works for returning the sum between two columns/vectors:

```
SELECT Cost_0 + Rev_0 FROM myTestDb.dbo.COST, myTestDb.dbo.REVENUE;
```

I thus assumed that I would be able to use this line of code in an update block in my new table BREAK_EVEN:

```
UPDATE myTestDb.dbo.BREAK_EVEN
SET B_E0 = (SELECT Cost_0 + Rev_0 FROM myTestDb.dbo.COST, myTestDb.dbo.REVENUE);
```

When I run this, I get (0 row(s) affected), which leads me to two questions:

1. what is my code actually doing, and
2. what do I need to change so that I can set B_E0 = Cost_0 + Rev_0?

Comment: Sample data and desired results are really needed.  And you should learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Surprised it runs at all. The SELECT under the SET clause has no WHERE condition so would be returning a cross join of the the two tables. Almost sounds like there may be no data in any of the tables? Concur with @GordonLinoff, can yo provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE

```
    WITH qry1 AS
    (
    SELECT [SomeRecordID]  /*need some kind of record to reference when 
    updating existing values*/
       , Cost_0 + Rev_0 AS ResultSum
    FROM COST
    JOIN REVENUE ON /*YOU NEED TO DEFINE YOUR JOIN COLUMNS OR YOU WILL HAVE A 
    CARTESIAN JOIN*/
    )

    UPDATE BREAK_EVEN
    SET B_E0 = [ResultSum]
    FROM qry1
    JOIN BREAK_EVEN ON qry1.SomeRecordID = BREAK_EVEN.MatchingRecordID
    ;
```

Sorry if that is a bit ugly, but I do not know your record id's from your source tables and I do not know which records you are trying to update.

Since you want to use UPDATE, I am assuming you are updating current records.  If you are creating new records, you use the INSERT statement.

Hope that helps.